# Path creation using accelerometer and gyroscope

Tags: ios, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope

I am using TI sensor tags, and getting the raw data from this sensor in form of gyroscope (x,y,z) , accelerometer (x,y,z) and magnetometer (x,y,z). Is there a way to find out the path by which I am moving the sensor.I am rotating the sensor in circular path and want to draw the same path.